# SaveAs2 output file in wrong encoding

Tags: excel, vba

I an new in VBA, I wrote this code to help to convert `*.docx` to `*.txt`. It gives me an output but in wrong encoding.

```
Sub FileConverter()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sEveryFile As String, sSourcePath As String, sNewSavePath As String, InFileSuffix As String, OutFileSuffix As String
    Dim CurDoc As Object, WordApp As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    sSourcePath = "D:\test"
    sEveryFile = Dir(sSourcePath & "\*.docx")
    
    Do While sEveryFile <> ""
       Set CurDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(sSourcePath & "\" & sEveryFile, , , , , , , , , , , msoFalse)
       sNewSavePath = VBA.Strings.Replace(sSourcePath & "\" & sEveryFile, ".docx", ".txt")
       CurDoc.SaveAs2 sNewSavePath, Encoding:=65001, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
       CurDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
       sEveryFile = Dir
    Loop
    MsgBox "Done"

    Set CurDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

My test `.docx` file is wrote in Chinese and English, my output `.txt` file is encoding in `ANSI`, which should be `UTF-8` in my desire. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You use `wdFormatText` in Excel where it is not defined because it is a Word constant and you used *"late binding"* therefore `wdFormatText` is treated as a variable and since it is not defined it is `0` which means according to the [WdSaveFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveformat) *"Microsoft Office Word 97 - 2003 binary file format."* • To save as text format you need either to use `FileFormat:=2` or define `Const wdFormatText = 2` before using it.

Comment: I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* to not run into such an issue and get notified if variables are not declared. Also remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. If you don't see your errors you cannot fix them. Nothing is worse than an error you cannot see. Check out [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, your anwser is right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine 
I use the text below in my docx file (english + chinese)

```
Here is my text in English
這是我的中文文本
```

the encoding UTF-8 is 65001 in Windows, so please could you check that you can save a .txt file with the UTF-8 encoding

Comment: I use this VBA program in Excel, not Word. And it is the problem of `wdFormatText`

Comment: wdFormatText = 2 in my side